# Secure a Wcf json web service without Window authentication

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'd like to secure a web service. I have to avoid window authentication because the hosting company will cause me some problems

How is it possible ? The best option for me if to configure the user / password (or just the password. it would be enought for that web service) into the web.config file.

I imagine I can add a special parameter but it seems ugly

My configuration is :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="ct.WebServices.WsCT">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ct.WebServices.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ct.WebServices.WsCT"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ct.WebServices.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1000000"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The web service is used by android device

The code is :

```
namespace ct.WebServices
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class WsCT
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/modif")]
        public IList<Ws.Modification> GetModifs() { return null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly discourage you from storing passwords in the Web.config.....

Comment: Oauth might be a solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH

Comment: I'l like to avoid storing the password into the windows 2012 user table because my sys admin will have problems with that. (in case of reinstall etc.)